# Assigning an HTML id to JQuery in if statement?

Tags: jquery, html

**HTML**

```
<fieldset class="col-sm-6">
    <label for="FDestination" >From</label>
    <select name="Location" >
        <option value = "Please Select" id = "DefaultDes" >Please Select </option>
        <option value="Newport">Newport</option>
        <option value="Mahdi">Mahdi</option>
        <option value="Cardiff">Cardiff</option>
        <option value="Cilo">Cilo is </option>
    </select>
</fieldeset>
```

**JQuery**

```
$document.ready(function(){

    var form = $(".group");
    var Destination = $(".col-sm-6"); //Creates Variables from forms 
    var Timing = $(".time");
    var Calenar = $(".calendar"); 

    form.submit (function (){

        if (validateName() & validateDestination & validateTiming & validateCalendar(){ //If it passes all of these then return true 

            return true;
        } else  {
                return : false;
        }

    }); 

    function validateDestination () {

        if (Destination.val() == DefaultDes) {

            Destination.addClass("error");
            Destination.text("Incorrect Destination"); 
            return: false; 
        }else {

            Destination.removeClass("error"); 
            Destination.text("Whats your name?" ); 
            return:true; 
        }
    }
};
```

So I am trying to get my id `DefaultDes` from HTML into an `if` statement in JQuery. Right now I have:

```
if (Destination.val() == DefaultDes)
```

in JQuery but syntax looks iffy. What I'm basically trying to do is when user selects the "Please select value" (with id `DefaultDes`) in HTML they are displayed an error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's a few things off here.

A `<select>` element has a `value` (jquery `.val()`) equal to the `value=".."` property of its selected `option`.

I could be new to the `fieldset` element, but I don't think they have their own values. So you're taking the `val()` from the wrong element; you want the `<select>`'s value.

That will come back as a string, so you don't need to compare elements (and if you did, you wouldn't want to use `==` between JQuery objects). Just check if the resulting `val()` equals `Please Select`. (For cleaner code, you could give that option a blank value, in which case it would still show the same text but not need such a wonky string comparison in code)

Comment: Thankyou I didnt fully understand your answer but would this be valid? - function validateDestination () {
        $(".col-sm-6").validate({
            
            message :{
                Location:  {
                    
                Destination.addClass("error");
                Destination.text("Incorrect Destination"); 
                return: false; 
                }
                
                
                
            }
        });
        };

Comment: @elmashrafi I may not be the best person to ask; I have little knowledge of JQ's `validate` function. What you put in your comment doesn't appear to be valid JavaScript though (I think it needs a function keyword somewhere)